# SVN pre-commit hooks from windows to linux

Tags: linux, windows, svn, pre-commit-hook

I have two PC in my network:
1) CentOs
2) Windows 7

I created repository on Linux machine and add some pre-commit hook scripts. Then, I checked out files to working copy directories on both machines. Now, when I make some changes and commit them from linux working copy then pre-commit hooks works as they should. But when I commit my changes from Windows (using Tortoise or command line) commit execute but without any results of working scripts.

I have read, that scripts are lunched on PC that holds repository (correct me if I'm wrong), so it shouldn't be matter of what kind of platform I'm making changes.

So, if any one can explain me why this doesn't work from windows then I would be grateful?

Answer (score 0):

The pre-commit hook is run by the machine that's hosting the server.  If you're using the repository with a `file://` URL or using `svnlook` or `svnadmin` commands then that's always the local machine since there isn't actually a server and the repository is accessed directly.

From the what you're saying it sounds to me like you're putting the repository on a network volume (SMB, NFS, etc) and then using a `file://` URL to access it.  If you use one of the other access methods then you won't have this problem.

You have 3 options.

**svnserve**

svnserve is a simple daemon that provides the `svn://` access method.  It listens on its own network port and talks a protocol that's specific to Subversion.

**svnserve over ssh**

The svnserve protocol is tunneled over ssh and a svnserve process is started on demand.

**Apache HTTP**

The mod_dav_svn and mod_authz_svn modules provide access to Subversion via an Apache httpd server.  This uses the DAV and DeltaV protocols over HTTP (optionally with SSL/TLS support).

The SVN Book has a [whole section on server setup](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.html) that covers choosing the server to how to configure it.  You probably want to read this before you make a choise and then read the configuration steps for your chosen server.